# Create soft links from multiple specific files in various subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, symlink

I want to create soft links (`ln -s`) to `folder2` of all the files that contain `*foo*` in its name, and can be found in some or all the subdirectories of `folder1`.

I've tried it with `for`, `find`, and `find -exec ln`, and a combination of them, but all I get is a broken link named `*foo*` or a link to everything inside `folder1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this little snippet

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1="/path/to/folder1"
find "$folder1" -type f -name '*foo*' -exec \ 
sh -c 'for f; do ln -s "$folder1" "/path/to/folder2/${f##*/}"; done' _ {} +
```

This can run from anywhere since I'm using absolute paths here.